# Error Implementing Google Analytics to iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-analytics, tracking

I am trying to add Google Analytics to my iOS app. I have added all the right frameworks to Xcode. I followed through the SDK v3 startup guide. But when I added:

```
self.trackedViewName = @"About Screen";
```

to my `viewcontroller`, I got an error saying

> Property `trackedViewName` not found on object of type `ViewController`

On my `.h` file, I imported `GAITrackedViewController.h` and added `GAITrackedViewController` to the interface.

What do you think the problem could be?

Comment: Show your code (both h and m file content).

Comment: ViewController.h: 


    #import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

    @interface LockinViewController : GAITrackedViewController

Comment: ViewController.m:


    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.trackedViewName = @"About Screen";
    }

Answer (score 8):

You can try `screenName` instead of `trackedViewName`

```
self.screenName = @"About Screen";
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol GAITracker;
@interface GAITrackedViewController : UIViewController {
@private
    id<GAITracker> tracker_;
    NSString *trackedViewName_;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign)id<GAITracker> tracker;
@property(nonatomic, copy)NSString *trackedViewName;
@end
```

Paste this code on `GAITrackedViewController.h` file.
Then you can use `self.trackedName = @"Some Name";` easly.

Answer (score 1):

Check the answer from here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/migration

Users of Automatic Screen Tracking should replace references to GAITrackedViewController.trackedViewName with GAITrackedViewController.screenName.